# Rails asset pipeline custom folder and its dependents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory, assets, pipeline

I am trying to create a rails app and I have couple of css and js files to be added to rails app pipeline. These are;

```
    <link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/switchery/css/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/codrops-stepsform/css/component.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/bootsclertrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/plugins/summernote/css/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/plugins/codrops-dialogFx/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/codrops-dialogFx/dialog-sandra.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="pages/css/pages-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link class="main-stylesheet" href="pages/css/themes/simple.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link class="main-stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

as in the theme I am trying to use. But if I only separate these css js and image, the problem is some of the css files are using img files inside their directory.For instance, `select2.css` uses b`ackground: url('select2.png') right top no-repeat;` Or bootstrap min (I know I can add gem for this) uses url path to `src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot)`. So should I go over css and js files and search for their dependents?

I am so stuck in to designing this in a rails way. Thank you

Comment: change background: url('select2.png') like background: url('/assets/select2.png'), Put your all css ,js & images in the app/assets folder & include them with rails include syntax , read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma or shall I add them to vendor assets?. The thing is I think I have to over each of the css file and change url of images

Comment: You need to change the url of each image, because by default the image is searched in the app/assets folder , if image is not found then searched in public/assets folder. If you add the assets in vendor folder , then also you need to change the url of images